# How to count Booleans in Haskell without using count?

Tags: haskell

There is a list of Booleans and I need to return True if the list contains an odd number of True components. But I don't know where to start. Any help would be grateful.

Comment: Did you try `odd . length . filter (== True) $ list` where `list` is your list of Booleans?

Comment: I ended up doing it this way
    
    xor = \bs -> if mod (length(filter(== True) bs)) 2 == 0 then False else True

Thanks for the help

Comment: `odd . sum . map fromEnum`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want a function that looks like this:

```
f x True  = not x
f x False = x
```

This function uses the first argument as a "state", if the second argument is `True` then flip `x`, if the second argument is `False` then don't do anything to `x`.  You can then use `foldl` (or `Data.List.foldl'` for better performance) to determine if the number of `True`s in a list is odd:

```
hasOddTrues :: [Bool] -> Bool
hasOddTrues bs = foldl f False bs
```

This code is equivalent to the Python code

```py
def f(x, y):
    if y: return not x
    else: return x

def hasOddTrues(bs):
    isOdd = False
    for b in bs:
        isOdd = f(isOdd, b)
    return isOdd
```

in that `fold`s generalize the concept of iterating over a collection of items with a state that changes on each iteration depending on the previous value and the current element.

Comment: Isn't your `f` function just `(/=) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool`? I think it's clearer what is going on if you think of it as just `xor`ing the N items in the list (since for Bools, xor is the same as /=).

Comment: Why not just write `odd . length . filter (== True)`? It's more readable. Plus due to [stream fusion](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1br0ls/haskell_beats_c_using_generalised_stream_fusion/) it would run quite efficiently.